# How can i get the textfield value from tag in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios4

if i have a tag of text field then how can i pick the value of textfield in iPhone sdk

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you should be fine with something like (assuming that the TextField is a self.view's subview):

```
NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:THE_TAG] text];
```

Answer (score 5):

NSString *text = [(UITextField *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag] text];

Answer (score 4):

Try below one

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:tag_Number];
NSString* textString=[textField text];
//Use textString  further
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:100];

NSLog(@"%@",textField.text);
```

You need to replace 100 by your own tag.

Comment: @JaspreetSingh: with pleasure